# Multicontext FPGAs

Tags: fpga, configuration

I recently read some papers that mentioned multicontext FPGAs, which have several copies of every programming bit. This allows to download a bitstream to the board while the active context (the aforementioned programming bits are multiplexed) performs computing tasks. This is different from partial reconfiguration in that the context switch requires a complete reconfiguration of the programming bits. My question is: do they actually exist? Or is it just a theoretical model yet?

Edit:
This is the first paper where I first found the concept: Compton, K., & Hauck, S. (2002). Reconfigurable computing: a survey of systems and software. ACM Computing Surveys (csuR), 34(2), 171-210.

Here's the link to it: https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=508352.508353

Comment: Sure, I added the reference to the paper that aroused my question. I found the rest of them just by looking up the concept in Google. I just read over the titles.

Comment: Sounds theoretical since the first to implement it would probably be Altera or Xilinx and if they did they would advertise it to high hell.

Comment: You could note the company [mentioned](https://people.ece.uw.edu/hauck/publications/ConfigCompute.pdf) Chameleon Systems Inc. went through [bankruptcy proceedings in 2004](https://www.courtlistener.com/opinion/1950296/in-re-chameleon-systems-inc/). The technology hurdle is the bandwidth (bus width versus size) to transfer a context. There's also a company [Stretch Inc.](http://www.stretchinc.com) that had a 10 context device that could not virtualize contexts. Their devices have since become overly specialized. They have expiring patents that would teach their earlier devices.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answers. That was clarifying.